# Nonstationary panel data, spurious regression

Tags: panel-data, stationarity, spurious-correlation

I would like a more detailed explanation of this quote:

> "Unlike the single time series spurious regression literature, the panel data spurious regression estimates give a consistent estimate of the true value of the parameter as both N and T tend to infinity. This is because, the panel estimator averages across individuals and the information in the independent cross-section data in the panel leads to a stronger overall signal than the pure time series case."
>   (from Baltagi's Econometric Analysis of Panel Data).

I find it odd. How can spurious regression provide consistent estimate of the true value (typical spurious regression yields non-zero coefficient estimates, while the true value is zero)?

The quote above gives me the impression that in a panel environment, one does not need to worry about the nonstationarity of the variables. Is this correct?

Answer (score 11):

Admittedly a bit confusing wording from Baltagi in this specific excerpt. But unfortunately, the expression "spurious regression" has come to be used in the econometrics literature as a synonym for "non-stationary and non-cointegrated regression"

Let's first attempt to clarify what the "spurious regression phenomenon" is:

> **Spurious regression** : when the estimation method produces a
>   statistically significant relation between two variables,
>   *irrespective of whether such a relation exists or not*.

And the phenomenon typically arises when the processes are not-stationary, and not co-integrated.

Note carefully that a relation *may indeed exist* -under "spurious regression" we do *not* describe the case where such a relation does not exist, but the estimator produces a phoney one. The problem lies in the fact that since we will get a statistically significant relation in all cases, we cannot tell whether what we see is actual or an artifact.

Then, Philips and Moon (see [this 2000 paper](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07474930008800473) of theirs for an accessible exposition) showed that in a panel-data setting, the regression stops being spurious, but it consistently estimates what actually is there -if there is a relation, it will estimate the relation, if there is not a relation, it will estimate zero. But, this will happen under *two-dimensional* asymptotics, i.e. as both $n$ *and* $T$ go to infinity. After all, the intuition behind this result, is exactly the exploitation of the two-dimensional information provided by a panel-data structure.

But I would refrain from general assertions like "we don't have to worry about non-stationary (and non-cointegrated) panels" - one should first study and understand the theoretical results and under which conditions (and for which kind of panels) do they hold.